# Remove star letters from console screen c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am new in c++ so,I am challenging myself with implementing sample projects.my current challenge is to input 'a','b','c','d' from user and write it in Uppercase letter in stars character and user can enter those letters for limitless times:

[image: Console output]

I write this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

#include<conio.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include<winuser.h>

using namespace std;

void moveCursor(int a,int b)
{
    COORD p;
    p.X=a;
    p.Y=b;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), p);
}

int main()
{
    int x=0,y=0,j=0;
    char lst_chr[100];
    int lst_chr_i=0;
bool col=true;

for(int i=0;;i++)
{
  while(col)
  {
    char chr=getch();
    if(chr=='a'||chr=='b'||chr=='c'||chr=='d'){
        lst_chr_i++;
        lst_chr[lst_chr_i]=chr;
    }


    switch(chr)
    {
      case 'x':
        return 0;
        break;

      case 'a':
        moveCursor(x,y++);
        cout << "    *";
        moveCursor(x,y++);
        cout << "   * *";
        moveCursor(x,y++);
        cout << "  *   *";
        moveCursor(x,y++);
        cout << " * * * *";
        moveCursor(x,y);
        cout << "*       *";
        j++;
        break;

      case 'b':
        moveCursor(x,y++);
        cout << "***";
        moveCursor(x,y++);
        cout << "*   *";
        moveCursor(x,y++);
        cout << "***";
        moveCursor(x,y++);
        cout << "*   *";
        moveCursor(x,y);
        cout << "***";
        j++;
        break;

     case 'c':
        moveCursor(x,y++);
        cout << "  **** ";
        moveCursor(x,y++);
        cout << " *    ";
        moveCursor(x,y++);
        cout << "*      ";
        moveCursor(x,y++);
        cout << " *    ";
        moveCursor(x,y);
        cout << "  **** ";
        j++;
        break;

     case 'd':
        moveCursor(x,y++);
        cout << "*** ";
        moveCursor(x,y++);
        cout << "*  * ";
        moveCursor(x,y++);
        cout << "*   *";
        moveCursor(x,y++);
        cout << "*  * ";
        moveCursor(x,y);
        cout << "*** ";
        j++;
        break;
     case 8:
         switch(lst_chr[lst_chr_i]){
              case 'a':
              //here remove if last entered char is a
              break;
           default:
              break;
         }
         lst_chr_i--;
        break;
    case 127:
        cout << "------------------";
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    if(chr!=8){
        if(j==10)
        {
          j=0;
          x=j*10;
          y=i*5+5;
          break;
       }

      x=j*10;
      y=i*5;
    }


 }

}


}
```

Now, I want to remove last star letter if user enter `Backspace` key. I tried but I don't know how to move back the cursor and remove each star and wait for user to enter new letter.

Comment: If you want to challenge yourself, start by removing all the code that advances the virtual cursor, and output the characters in the same location. Observe the effect of overwriting previous output. In light of that knowledge ask yourself, whether you already have everything to "clear" a character. As an aside: Choosing variable names `i` and `j` challenges readers of your code, for all the wrong reasons. Pick names that communicate the purpose instead.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can't remove characters from console screen, instead you have to fill them with spaces. So, just put the cursor at needed position and print spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I improved your code and can successfully solve your problem.

The following is my test object with`'a'`, you can add more characters to complete the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <conio.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>

#pragma warning(disable:4996)
using namespace std;

void moveCursor(int a, int b)
{
    COORD p;
    p.X = a;
    p.Y = b;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), p);
}

int main()
{
    int x = 0, y = 0, j = 0;
    char lst_chr[100] = { 0 };
    int lst_chr_i = 0;
    bool col = true;
    bool flag = false;
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int k1 = 1;     
    while (col)
    {  
            i = (lst_chr_i) / 10;
            if (i)
            {
                k = lst_chr_i / (10 * k1);
                if (k)
                {
                    j = 0;
                    x = j * 10;
                    y = i * 5;
                    k1++;
                }

            }            
           
            char chr = getch();
            if (chr == 'a') {               
                lst_chr[lst_chr_i] = chr;
                lst_chr_i++;
            }
            
            switch (chr)
            {
            case 'x':
                return 0;
                break;

            case 'a':
                moveCursor(x, y++);
                cout << "    *";
                moveCursor(x, y++);
                cout << "   * *";
                moveCursor(x, y++);
                cout << "  *   *";
                moveCursor(x, y++);
                cout << " * * * *";
                moveCursor(x, y);
                cout << "*       *";
                j++;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

            if (chr != '\b') 
            {                              
                x = j * 10;
                y = i * 5;
            }
            else if(chr == '\b')
            { 
                if (i != 0 && x==0)
                {
                    --i;
                    --k1;
                    y = i * 5;                   
                    j = 9;
                    x = j * 10;
                }
                else
                {
                    y = i * 5;
                    x = --j * 10;
                }
                if (x <= 0)
                {
                   x = 0;
                   j = 0;
                }
                char chr_ = lst_chr[--lst_chr_i];
                if (lst_chr_i < 0)
                {
                    lst_chr_i = 0;
                }
                lst_chr[lst_chr_i] = '0';
                switch (chr_) {
                case 'a':
                    //here remove if last entered char is a
                    moveCursor(x, y++);
                    cout << "     ";
                    moveCursor(x, y++);
                    cout << "      ";
                    moveCursor(x, y++);
                    cout << "       ";
                    moveCursor(x, y++);
                    cout << "        ";
                    moveCursor(x, y);
                    cout << "         ";
                    moveCursor(x, i * 5);

                    y = i * 5;
                    
                    break; 
                }

            }

            
    }


}
```

Debug:

[image]